# connect user with out quotation marks in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

**CREATE USER "USER01" IDENTIFIED BY "1234";**

and try to connect

**connect USER01/1234**

it dosen't work!

only **connect "USER01"/1234**  is possible

how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Both of your examples work for me (after running `grant create session to user01;`).  I don't see why quotation marks would matter here, since the user was created with all upper case.  It might help to post a fully reproducible test case in SQL\*Plus.  Something that we can all copy and paste exactly the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle is case sensitive if the username was created with quotation marks and lower case characters.  Once a user is created as case sensitive, it must always be referenced with quotation marks and the correct case.  The same rule applies to almost all objects, like table names and column names.

The code and the screenshot don't quite match.  `USER01` is all uppercase, it can be referenced either with or without quotation marks.  But `st01` must have been created with quotation marks, and now must always be referenced as `"st01"`.

Oracle recommends not to use case sensitive object names, to avoid these situations.  Often times, tools will always add quotation marks around object names, just in case one of them is case sensitive.  But this can cause a problem if we copy and paste that code and change it, because we may accidentally make the object case sensitive.

This is confusing enough for native English speakers.  This must really suck if your native language doesn't have uppercase and lowercase characters.

영어로 프로그래밍은 짜증나.